# iPhone 4 images: how many pixels per inch?

Tags: iphone

When trying to create an image for a native iPhone 4 app, what should the image resolution be in Photoshop? how many pixels per inch? Does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1) A 24″ 1920×1200 screen is roughly 20.4 inches wide; 1920 / 20.4 = 94 PPI.
2) An iPhone 3G has a screen 2.024 inches wide; 320 / 2.024 = 158 PPI.
3) An iPhone 4 has a screen 1.965 inches wide; 640 / 1.965 = 326 PPI.
```

Refer following link for more detail :

- http://miekd.com/articles/dpi-ppi-and-photoshop-style-presets/
- http://www.ethervision.net/development-processes/design-basics-iphone-ipad/
- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/17/designing-for-iphone-4-retina-display-techniques-and-workflow/

Answer (score 0):

The iphone 4 comes with retina display so the image size should be 2 the normal image, eg normal 320 in retina it will be 640.

If supporting both screen dispay check the naming convention like,

With retina image@2x.png, without retina image.png.

Hope this help u.